# What are the things to watch out for with case insensitive regex replace?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, case-insensitive

I have written the following code to do case insensitive replace in C#:

```
Regex.Replace(textBoxText, 
    Regex.Escape(findText), 
    replaceText, 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Just wanted to check, whether this is the right approach, or is there a better approach and whether I'm overlooking something that I should better be aware of.

Note: Please don't provide me some hand crafted code, I had used a fast replace function from codeproject, and that code crashes at client side, and I have no way to know, what input the user was using. So, I prefer some simple but correct and reliable method.

Comment: I agree this is NOT a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code seems ok, but remember that when you do case-insensitive matching like that, you use the current locale or culture. It is probably better to add the Culture you want, or have the user select it. `CultureInvariant` is usually a good general choice to act the same in any locale:

```
Regex.Replace(textBoxText, 
    Regex.Escape(findText), 
    replaceText, 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

To use another locale, you need to do a bit more hocus pocus:

```
// remember current
CultureInfo originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

// set user-selected culture here (in place of "en-US")
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

// do the regex
Regex.Replace(textBoxText, 
    Regex.Escape(findText), 
    replaceText, 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// reset the original culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
```

Note that you can switch case insensitivity on or off. It is not a toggle, that means that:

```
// these three statements are equivalent and yield the same results:
Regex.Replace("tExT", "[a-z]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex.Replace("tExT", "(?i)[a-z]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex.Replace("tExT", "(?i)[a-z]", "");

// once IgnoreCase is used, this switches it off for the whole expression...
Regex.Replace("tExT", "(?-i)[a-z]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

//...and this can switch it off for only a part of the expression:
Regex.Replace("tExT", "(?:(?-i)[a-z])", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The last one is interesting: between the `(?:)` after the non-capturing grouping parenthesis, the case-switch `(?-i)` is not effective anymore. You can use this as often as you like in an expression. Using it without grouping makes them effective until the next case-sensitivity switch, or to the end.

***Update:*** I made the wrong assumption that you can't do case-sensitivity switching. The text above is edited with this in mind.

Comment: I didn't get this part: 'but that it is not possible to switch case-sensitivity'? Also how to set the locale for comparison?

Comment: Sorry, was interrupted by a phone call and hit submit too quickly. See my edits, it answers both your questions, I think.

Comment: the regex is basically user input which is escaped, so that it won't ask like an invalid regex sometimes. So, I think RegexOptions.CultureInvariant is the better choice. Also I am looking for English only.

Comment: Then `CultureInvariant` is the way to go as there are few differences (if any) with English. You can also explicitly set the culture to British or Am. English as described above. Obviously, if you use `Regex.Escape`, users cannot use any regular expression powers, it's just a string. No need for regexes anymore. Just use `String.Replace`, which will give you better performance (and also case-insensitivity).

Comment: "Just use String.Replace, which will give you better performance (and also case-insensitivity)." -- Does String.Replace provide case-insensitivity, I don't think so.

Comment: My apologies, you are absolutely right! I was confused with the comparison switches. You need to use `ToLowerInvariant`, but then you change the whole string, which may not be what you want.